# Scene object selective export using Blender Python API 2.6

Tags: python, scripting, 3d, blender

I am writing a custom export script to parse all the objects in a blender file, filter them by name, then check to make sure that they meet some specific criteria.

I am using Blender 2.68a. I've created a blender file with some basic 2d and 3d meshes, as well as some that should fail my test criteria. I am working in the internal Python console inside of Blender. This is the only way to work with the blender python API, as their python environment is customized.

I've sorted how to iterate through the objects using a for loop and the D.objects iterator, then check for name matches using regular expressions, and then get a mesh from the object using:

```
mesh = obj.to_mesh(C.scene, True, 'RENDER') #where obj is an bpy.data.object[index] in the scene
mesh.update(True, True) 
mesh.polygons[index].<long list of possible functions>
```

lets me access an array of polygons to know if there is a set of vertices with edges that form a polygon, and what their key values are.

What I can't sort out is how to determine from the python console if a poly is a face or just a poly. Is there a built in function, or what tests can i perform to programmatically determine this? For example, I can have a mesh 4 vertices with 4 edges that do not have a face, and I do not want to export this, but if i were to edit the same 4 vertices/edges and put a face on it, then it becomes a desirable export.

Can anyone explain the bpy.data.object data structure or explain where the "faces" are stored? it seems as though it would be a property of the npolys themselves, but the API does not make it obvious. Any assistance in clarifying this would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: A mesh model is made up of vertices, edges and faces. A face is just another name for polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i asked this question on the blender.org forums, http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28286&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0 and a very helpful individual has helped me over the past few days each time I got stuck in my own efforts to plow through this.

The short list of answers is:

1) All polygons are faces. If it isnt stored as a polygon, it isnt a face.
2) using the to_mesh() function on an object returns a copy of the function, and so any selections that are done to the copy are not reflected by the context and therefore the methodology I was using was flawed. The only way to access the live object is through use of:

```
bpy.data.objects[<index or object name>].data.vertices[<index>].co[<0,1,2> which correspond to x,y,z respectively]  
bpy.data.objects[<index or object name>].data.polygons[<index>].edge_keys
```

The first one gives you access to an ordered index of all the vertices in the object(assuming it is of type 'MESH'), and their coordinates.
The second one gives you access to an 2d array of ordered pairs which represent edges. The numbers it contains within the tuples correspond to the index value in the vertices list from the first command, and so you can get the coordinates which the edge goes between. 
One can also create a new BMesh object and copy the object you are interested in into the BMesh. This gives you a lot  more functionality that you can't access on the live object. The code in answer 3 shows an example of this.

3)see below for answer to my question regarding checking faces in a mesh.

it turns out that one way to determine if an object has faces and all edges are a part of a face is to use the following code snippet written by a helpful user, CoDEmanX on the above thread.

```
import bpy, bmesh 

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects: 
    if ob.type != 'MESH': 
        continue
    bm = bmesh.new() 
    bm.from_object(ob, bpy.context.scene) 

    if len(bm.faces) > 0 and 0 not in (len(e.link_faces) for e in bm.edges): 
        print(ob.name, "is valid") 
    else: 
        print(ob.name, "has errors")
```

I changed this a little bit, as i didnt want it to loop through all the objects, and instead i've got this as a function that returns true if the object passed in is valid and false otherwise. This lets me serialize my calls so that my addon only tries to validate the objects which have a name which matches a regex.

```
def validate(obj):
    import bpy, bmesh 

    if obj.type == 'MESH':                
        bm = bmesh.new() 
        bm.from_object(obj, bpy.context.scene) 

        if len(bm.faces) > 0 and 0 not in (len(e.link_faces) for e in bm.edges): 
            return True
    return False
```